# Forcing a viewcontroller to be portrait monotouch iphone

Tags: ios, iphone, uiviewcontroller, xamarin.ios, rotation

I have a view controller in my app that want to show always in prtaint mode. The objects of this screen is added in runtime and based on the protaint mode. It is my first viewcontroller.

I tried some codes such as:

[first](http://b2cloud.com.au/how-to-guides/forcing-uiviewcontroller-orientation)

[second](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10316683/force-interface-orientation-landscape-on-a-viewcontroller-when-the-rest-of-the-a)

[Third](http://monotouch.2284126.n4.nabble.com/Having-1-ViewController-with-different-orientation-td4656971.html)

but none of them couldent help me. can know any other solution for this state?

i found some thing there:

[Monotouch - View created in landscape orientation is displayed in portrait orientation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8014810/monotouch-view-created-in-landscape-orientation-is-displayed-in-portrait-orien)

but i dont know how to use this. can any body help?

i use this codes

```
public override bool ShouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation (UIInterfaceOrientation toInterfaceOrientation)
        {
            // Return true for supported orientations
            if (UserInterfaceIdiomIsPhone) {
                return (toInterfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientation.PortraitUpsideDown  );
            } else {
                return true;
            }

        }


        public override bool ShouldAutorotate ()
        {
            return true  ;
        }
        public override UIInterfaceOrientation PreferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation ()
        {
            return UIInterfaceOrientation.Portrait ;
        }

    public override UIInterfaceOrientationMask GetSupportedInterfaceOrientations ()
        {
            return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Portrait  ;
        }
```

but none of them works.

autoroatate function never calls :(

Comment: So you have multiple Orientations in different views? In your "Supported interface orientations" you have all four ticked? And it's only in the one launched at runtime that you want to always be in portrait, is that a correct assumption?

Comment: Yes, the view controller is my first view controller in my app that I want to be portrait and also in supported interface orientaions I have 3 of fours

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you are using Navigation controller in you app finished lunching mode. If right you should override UINavigation controller and add yous own rotaion mechanism to this. Please see this code:

```
public class RltNavigationController : UINavigationController
{
    public RltNavigationController () : base ()
    {
    }

    public override UIInterfaceOrientationMask GetSupportedInterfaceOrientations ()
    {
        if(this.TopViewController is HomeScreen )
            return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Portrait ;
        else 
            return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.AllButUpsideDown  ;

    }

    public override bool ShouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation (UIInterfaceOrientation toInterfaceOrientation)
    {
        // Return true for supported orientations
        if(this.TopViewController is HomeScreen )
            return (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientation.Portrait );
        else 
            return (toInterfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientation.PortraitUpsideDown) ;

    }
}
```

Comment: ShouldAutotrotateToInterfaceOrientation is depricated as of iOS6

Comment: ShouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation is for ios 5 devices and GetSupportedInterfaceOrientations for ios 6 and upper. both methods has been overrided